# Where can I find locations in Hong Kong for PCR testing and for staying overnight?

Tags: airports, covid-19, hong-kong

Can you take a PCR test at the airport in Hong Kong in order to enter the mainland? How much does it cost and do you need to make an appointment?

What is the earliest possible time to book a slot and how long does it usually take once an appointment is made? Could a PCR test done at a place other than the airport or the border be accepted when entering the mainland?

Additionally, if I need to stay overnight at the airport, do I have to enter Hong Kong and is it safer to stay outside of Hong Kong rather than entering in order to stay overnight at the airport?

Does taking a PCR test at the airport require me to enter Hong Kong, and if I have to enter Hong Kong to take the PCR test and then stay outside of Hong Kong to stay at the airport, is it possible to stay overnight at the airport?

Comment: I believe this question can be split as it has multiple sub-questions that are sufficiently apart. Having that said, info on [this press release](https://www.info.gov.hk/gia/general/202301/06/P2023010600339.htm) and [this website](https://www.communitytest.gov.hk/en/) may be helpful.

Comment: Thanks .

Which testing sites would you consider? 
I was wondering if it's a good idea to test at a site between the airport and the station for high speed trains?

Where can I find some free or economic place to stay ? Ideally also between the airport and the station?
Is it possible to take a test somewhere, and then come back to the airport for overnight stay?